# Trouble enabling 8443 on Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I enabled the connector for port 8443 on my Apache Tomcat 7 web server. When I try to access a deployed application (https://myserver:8443/myapplication/) or the tomcat manager on 8443, however, the page does not resolve. I'm wondering if I missed a step?  Tomcat starts without any errors or warnings.  Here are the changes that I made:

Allowed port 8443 on my firewall and uncommented the 8443 connector in server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="/var/lib/tomcat7/localhost.jks"
           keystorePass="mypassword" keyAlias="localhost" />
```

I added the following to catalina.sh:

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/lib/tomcat7/localhost.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/var/lib/tomcat7/localhost.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypassword -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypassword"

Finally, I restarted Tomcat:

```
Nov 9, 2012 10:51:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 9, 2012 10:51:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Nov 9, 2012 10:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 574 ms
Nov 9, 2012 10:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 9, 2012 10:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Nov 9, 2012 10:51:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myapplication.war
Nov 9, 2012 10:51:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

Nov 9, 2012 10:51:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'grails'
Nov 9, 2012 10:51:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Nov 9, 2012 10:51:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 9, 2012 10:51:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Nov 9, 2012 10:51:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13439 ms
```

As you can see, it started ProtocolHandler for 8443.

Do I need to change the alias name of my certificate to the real server name rather than localhost? That is the only thing that I can think of. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Here is the nmap for port 8443:

```
$nmap -p 8443 localhost
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-11-10 02:47 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000091s latency).
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8443/tcp open  https-alt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

Thanks!

---

**Catalina.out after adding Djavax.net.debug=all to catalina.sh:**

```
...
Nov 11, 2012 4:24:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'grails'
Nov 11, 2012 4:24:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Nov 11, 2012 4:24:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 11, 2012 4:24:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
http-bio-8443-Acceptor-0, called closeSocket()
Nov 11, 2012 4:24:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13399 ms
```

Comment: Port 443 is also open, does it somehow need to be mapped to 8443?

Comment: What happens if you don't include the -Djavax.net* params at startup?

Comment: I tried removing all of the -Djavax.net* params from catalina.sh, and I see the same exact behavior.

Comment: OK. I don't think localhost should be an issue. I assume non SSL is working. To debug you could try `-Djavax.net.debug=all`

Comment: I added Djavax.net.debug=all and aside from showing a lot of certificate information, I see nothing out of the ordinary. I have posted what I believe to be the relevant parts of catalina.out in the original post. Can you see anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm embarrassed.  It turns out that if I navigate to the actual IP address, then it works (as opposed to the domain name). It seems that I will need to provide a mapping somewhere (does anyone know where?) so that it resolves with the domain name....

Comment: When you ping your domain name, does it looks responding ? Are your sure your domain is in hosts or in a local/remote DNS ?

Answer (score 0):

open  /etc/hosts file in sudo mode

Here you can do mapping of ip to domain name.